# Combined use of map and group for transforming array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I need some help for combining map and group to transform my data:

```
const source = [
  { _id: { hour: 18, score: 1 }, value: 45 },
  { _id: { hour: 18, score: 5 }, value: 23 },
  { _id: { hour: 18, score: 4 }, value: 34 },
  { _id: { hour: 20, score: 1 }, value: 47 },
  { _id: { hour: 20, score: 5 }, value: 25 },
  { _id: { hour: 20, score: 4 }, value: 36 },
  { _id: { hour: 19, score: 1 }, value: 46 },
  { _id: { hour: 19, score: 5 }, value: 24 },
  { _id: { hour: 19, score: 4 }, value: 35 }
]
```

This is how the result should look like:

```
{
  label: [18, 19, 20], // reordered hour values
  datasets: [
    { // each sorted score should get the values in an array sorted by hour
      data: [45, 46, 47],
      score: 1
    },
    {
      data: [34, 35, 36],
      score: 4
    },
    {
      data: [23, 24, 25],
      score: 5
    }
  ]
}
```

So for the label I'm just doing

```
const label = data.map(d => d._id.hour)
```

How do I get the dataset `data` for *each* score? I would think of a loop:

```
label.forEach(function(element) {
  datasets.push({
    data: source.filter(d => d._id.hour === element).map(d => d.value),
    score: // ??
  })
})
```

But this is not working, as I do get all datasets of an hour, but I need some grouped data for the score.
And also with my attempt there is not sorting at all. Sorting for hour and score is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first have to iterate over the items to create a map of datasets indexed by `score`, whose values are an array of the current `value`s found for that score so far. On each iteration, create the array for the associated score first if it doesn't exist, then push to it. After iterating, take that map's entries and map it to a new array with `data` and `score` properties:

```js
const source = [
  { _id: { hour: 18, score: 1 }, value: 45 },
  { _id: { hour: 18, score: 5 }, value: 23 },
  { _id: { hour: 18, score: 4 }, value: 34 },
  { _id: { hour: 20, score: 1 }, value: 47 },
  { _id: { hour: 20, score: 5 }, value: 25 },
  { _id: { hour: 20, score: 4 }, value: 36 },
  { _id: { hour: 19, score: 1 }, value: 46 },
  { _id: { hour: 19, score: 5 }, value: 24 },
  { _id: { hour: 19, score: 4 }, value: 35 }
];

const getHour = item => item._id.hour;
source.sort((a, b) => getHour(a) - getHour(b));
const label = [...new Set(source.map(getHour))];
const datasetsObj = {};
for (const { value, _id: { score } } of source) {
  if (!datasetsObj[score]) {
    datasetsObj[score] = [];
  }
  datasetsObj[score].push(value);
}
const datasets = Object.entries(datasetsObj)
  .map(([score, data]) => ({ data, score }));
const output = { label, datasets };
console.log(output);
```